# Datepicker and TimePicker in a form, datepicker works fine but timePicker doesn't drop down in field

Tags: jquery-ui

First of all, I'm a novice at this stuff so excuse my "ignorance."

I am creating a form in order for customers to schedule a test drive on a vehicle they are interested in purchasing.  I have found jquery code which I've included in the head section as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ autoSize: true });
  $("#time1").timePicker();
  // 09.00 AM - 03.30 PM, 15 minutes steps.
  $("#time2").timePicker({
    startTime: "09.00",  // Using string. Can take string or Date object.
    endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 30, 0),  // Using Date object.
    show24Hours: false,
    separator:'.',
    step: 15
  });
});
```

In the form, I have added the following:

```
<b>Pick a Date and Time</b><br>
<span class="auto-style7">Date: </span>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="testdrivedate" style="width: 91px" /><br>
<span class="auto-style7">Time: </span>
<input type="text" id="time2" name="testdrivetime" size="10" value="09.00 AM" style="width: 87px"/><br>
```

The datepicker works well, when the user clicks in the field, the calendar shows up just below the field and when a date is selected, the field is populated with the date selected.

However, the timepicker field does not work.  09:00 AM appears in the form, but when the user clicks in the field, no drop down appears in order to allow for selection of a different time.

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks for any assistance.

Anna

Comment: No need to apologize for anything as long as you come to SO with a positive attitude. And just as you did, as long as you show us what you have tried, that you're willing to learn from the experience and not just demand answers, you are good to go! Also, providing a jsfiddle link is a huge +!

Comment: I got the coding from https://github.com/perifer/timePicker.  Not sure what you mean by a jsfiddle link.  Like I said, I'm a huge novice but can research the net to find out how to do what I need to do and try to make it work.  As I said, the datepicker portion works just fine.

Comment: So far, your code looks correct and similar to the demo. Did you make sure to include the timePicker.js file inside your code? Also, I noticed you also have timePicker called on #time1, is that one working? Is #time1 and #time2 both not working?

Comment: Oh and a jsfiddle allows us to see your code, edit it and execute it. It is helpful for both you and I to see what you have been trying. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Not using #time1 at all, I guess I could take that out.  I've not included timePicker.js, but I don't have datepicker.js either.  I've have added the following:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: How does jsfiddle work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment above, I would guess your code is not executing because you have not included `jquery.timePicker.js` in your code. [Download the file](https://github.com/perifer/timePicker) and include it like this:

```
 <script src="path/to/your/js/file/jquery.timePicker.js"></script>
```

You don't need to include datePicker.js because [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is a plugin included with the jquery-ui library. (So really you do have datepicker included!)

Also, looking at your comment, you do not need to have a `;` after declaring a `<script>` tag

Like this:

`<script></script>`

Not like this:

`<script></script>;`

**EDIT**

I found the issue, it appears the [jquery.timepicker.js](https://github.com/perifer/timePicker) library is quite old (2009). It was developed with a much older jquery version. When I run jquery.timepicker.js with a newer version of jquery, I get this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined` on jquery.timePicker.js line 130

When I checked line 130 in jquery.timepicker.js, the error was complaining about `$.browser` being `undefined`. You are using jquery 1.9.1, and as of jquery 1.9 the jquery website states this about the $.browser object:

`This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.`

See this page for more information on the jquery browser element: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

It looks like you would have to try and use the jquery.migrate plugin if you want to get `$.browser` and jquery.timepicker.js to work. I'm not sure how difficult this will be as I've never used the jquery.migrate plugin before.

As another a **solution**, it looks like jquery 1.8.3 plays nicely with both jquery.timepicker.js and jquery-ui 1.10.3 (which is what you are also using). You can either use jquery 1.8.3 instead of 1.9.1:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Or you should use the latest version of jquery, jquery-ui and a **newer** jquery timepicker plugin. On google search, the first entry for jquery timepicker is this one http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ dated May 5th, 2013 which is quite recent. That might work better for you.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't have ";" after </script>, don't know how that got there.  I'm having trouble downloading the file, any suggestions?

Comment: Two ways, you can click on the Download Zip button on the right side of the page. Or you can click on "jquery.timePicker.js" > Click on "Raw" > Save Page As [CTRL + S] (through Browser)

Comment: Got the file and placed it in a folder I have with a couple of other js files.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/jquery.timePicker.js"></script>

Comment: You might have to include the timePicker.css file too, especially if you are using Internet Explorer. I see some /* needed for IE */ comments in there. If you copy your code into a jsFiddle and save it (by pressing update) you can link the URL to me so I can see what all your code looks like instead of pasting snippets at a time. It'll help this go faster.

Comment: I'll try that, but in the meantime, here's the live link (sometimes the preview doesn't work right, so I tried publishing to the site to see how it behaves: www.fairfieldmitsubishict.com/ContactUs/ScheduleTestDrive.html

Comment: Ok, I'm closer to getting it to work.  However, it seems that when I select a time, it doesn't close the drop down.  I have to move off the field in order for it to do that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about that.. I edited my answer above though and I think it might be easier if you use a newer timepicker library.

Comment: One last question, your suggestion of earlier version of js works.  How do I get the end time to be something later than 3:30 pm? It's not obvious to me what I need to change to make that happen.

Comment: Nice work! :) As you browse this site more often you'll see working examples of how jsfiddles work, then you can use them to help describe  and solve your problem too. Good luck!